# Adding extra items to a form through javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been searching for awhile to get the following done: adding items to a form after the form has been passed. I already managed to add the HTML for the new item to the form, but after posting it is not recognized. So, let's make my problem a bit more clear:

I have an object, namely Project. In that project, I have a List, which contains name/email and a bool to check whether or not the member has been selected (through the use of a checkbox, ofcourse).

In the view, it generates a form where someone can enter the project details and select (pre-existing) members. There is a button as well, which can create new members. When the button is pushed, the project form is hidden and a new (PartialView/form) is presented. After filling out the required user details, it is sent through an AJAX request and a JSON object is returned.

The new user is added to the usertable, but the form does not seem to recognize the newly added member. I have checked the HTML that is generated by the helpers (@CheckBoxFor etc.) with the HTML that I inject into the table: it is the same.

I suspect that the form itself has to be reset in some way (rebinding?), but my search attempts have come up with nothing, execpt tutorials/stackoverflow questions that explain how to bind a model in a view, not the rebinding.

I apologize for the lack of code, I hope the explanation is enough.

Comment: if you can add some code then we will have better idea....!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you reading the [`Editing Variable Length List`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) article written by Steven Sanderson which illustrates a very nice approach to achieve that. The idea is that you should not use integers as indexes for the names of your input fields but Guids and use the `.index` special hidden field to indicate the index of the current row to the model binder. This way no matter how many fields you dynamically add or remove from the form the model binder will always be able to successfully bind the collection property.

In his article he also illustrated a nice `Html.BeginCollectionItem` custom HTML helper which hides this work.

Comment: This seems like a viable solution, I'm going to play around with this and see what I can do with it :)

Thnx!

Comment: Sadly enough it's not helping. There was something wrong with the id generation, but as it turns out that is not the issue. The original table with members is generated through a view, after that I add the new user in the table through jQuery. When I submit, it does not recognize the new member(s). The HTML that I inject into the table though, is the same as the HTML the view generates for me.

Comment: Did you read the article I've linked to? Did you use GUIDS instead of integers for your indexes? Did you use the `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper presented in this article to generate those input elements? If the answer to one of those questions is `no`, then it is normal that your code doesn't work.